# Calculate AUC by different segments in python

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, auc

I have a dataset which contains **id, datetime, model features, ground truth labels** and the **predicted probability**.

```
id     datetime   feature1   feature2   feature3   ...      label      probability
001   2023-01-01   a1          b3          c1      ...     Rejected       0.98
002   2023-01-04   a2          b1          c1      ...     Approved       0.28
003   2023-01-04   a1          b2          c1      ...     Rejected       0.81
004   2023-01-08   a2          b3          c2      ...     Rejected       0.97
005   2023-01-09   a2          b1          c1      ...     Approved       0.06
006   2023-01-09   a2          b2          c2      ...     Approved       0.06
007   2023-01-10   a1          b1          c2      ...     Approved       0.13
008   2023-01-11   a2          b2          c1      ...     Approved       0.18
009   2023-01-12   a2          b1          c1      ...     Approved       0.16
010   2023-01-12   a1          b1          c2      ...     Rejected       0.96
011   2023-01-09   a2          b3          c2      ...     Approved       0.16
...
```

I want to know what is the AUC of each segment under different features. How can I manipulate the dataset to get results?

What I have done is to use the groupby method on date to get the monthly AUC for all features together.

```
def group_auc(x, col_tar, col_scr):
    from sklearn import metrics
    return metrics.roc_auc_score(x[col_tar], x[col_scr])
def map_y(x):
    if x == 'Rejected':
        return 1
    elif x == 'Approved':
        return 0
    return x
## example
y_name = 'label'
df[y_name] = df[y_name].apply(map_y)
# Remove NA rows
df = df.dropna(subset = [y_name])
df['Month_Year'] = df['datetime'].dt.to_period('M')
group_data_monthly = df.groupby('Month_Year').apply(group_auc, y_name, 'probability').reset_index().rename(columns={0:'AUC'})
```

My expected output will be like,

```
datetime     features   value     AUC
2023-01-01   feature1    a1      0.98
2023-01-01   feature1    a2      ...
2023-01-01   feature1    a3      ...
2023-01-01   feature2    b1      ...
2023-01-01   feature2    b2      ...
2023-01-01   feature2    b3      ...
2023-01-01   feature3    c1      ...
2023-01-01   feature3    c2      ...
2023-01-04   feature1    a1      ...
2023-01-04   feature1    a2      ...
2023-01-04   feature1    a3      ...
2023-01-04   feature2    b1      ...
...
```

I have also tried to use `stack` method to transpose the dataframe, but the script failed due to the huge size of the dataframe.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Is this supposed to be a subsample analysis?

Comment: It's not totally clear what you are trying to do, can you expand the question? Some comments however: 
Given you have a datetime column, you can use pandas inbuilt resample function to group by months.
You already have a label, so unclear why you are changing it from a label to 1 / 0. This can be done much more efficiently with direct replacement than applying a function.

Comment: can you attach a reproducible example? maybe a `df.to_dict()`.

Comment: Can you provide the exact expected output (with real values)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop over the different columns you want to aggregate with

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score as auc

def group_auc(x,y_name,p_name='probability'):
    try:
        return auc(x[y_name],x[p_name])
    except ValueError:
        return np.nan

y_name = 'label'

df[y_name] = df[y_name].apply(lambda x:{'Rejected':1,'Approved':0}.get(x,x))
df = df.dropna(subset = [y_name])

group_data_list = []
for feature in ['feature1','feature2','feature3']:
    temp = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='datetime',freq='m'),feature])
    temp = temp.apply(lambda x: group_auc(x,y_name))
    temp = temp.reset_index()
    temp['features'] = feature
    temp = temp.rename(columns={feature:'value',0:'AUC'})
    group_data_list.append(temp.copy())
group_data = pd.concat(group_data_list)   
group_data[['datetime','features','value','AUC']]
```

Note that the `group_auc` function also needs an exception handling otherwise an exception will be raised when a group only contains 1 point.

Lastly I have taken the liberty of substituting the creation of an explicit `Month_Year` column with a `pd.Grouper` which gives a little more versatility. As the code is written the Time-Grouper can be removed and the code will still function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate the AUC of each feature for each segment (i.e., month), you can use the pandas `pivot_table` function. Here's an example code snippet that you can use:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import metrics

# load the dataset
df = pd.read_csv("your_dataset.csv")

# preprocess the dataset
df["label"] = df["label"].apply(lambda x: 1 if x == "Rejected" else 0)
df["Month_Year"] = pd.to_datetime(df["datetime"]).dt.to_period("M")

# calculate AUC for each feature and segment
feature_cols = ["feature1", "feature2", "feature3"]  # replace with your feature column names
auc_dict = {}
for feature_col in feature_cols:
    pivot_df = pd.pivot_table(df, index="Month_Year", columns=feature_col, values=["label", "probability"], aggfunc="mean")
    pivot_df = pivot_df.dropna()
    for feature_value in pivot_df.columns.levels[1]:
        y_true = pivot_df["label", feature_value]
        y_score = pivot_df["probability", feature_value]
        auc = metrics.roc_auc_score(y_true, y_score)
        auc_dict[(feature_col, feature_value)] = auc

# convert the AUC dictionary to a dataframe
auc_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(auc_dict, orient="index", columns=["AUC"]).reset_index()
auc_df = auc_df.rename(columns={"level_0": "features", "level_1": "value"})

# display the output
print(auc_df.head())
```

This code will create a pivot table where the rows are the segments (i.e., months), the columns are the feature values, and the values are the mean label and probability values for each group. Then, for each feature value, the code calculates the AUC and stores it in a dictionary. Finally, the AUC dictionary is converted to a dataframe and displayed.

Note that this code assumes that your dataset is stored in a CSV file named "your_dataset.csv". You'll need to replace this with the actual filename of your dataset. Also, you'll need to replace the list of feature column names with the actual names of the feature columns in your dataset.